# JQgrid: set dynamically format cell with cellattr and with dynamic number column

Tags: json, dynamic, jqgrid, format, cell

I first need to build dynamically the columns of grid, so I do:

```
success: function(data){
                  var colnames = data.colnames;
                  var colmodel = data.colmodel;
                  $("#list").jqGrid({       
                        ...
                        colNames: colnames,
                        colModel: colmodel,  
                        ...})
```

in my PHP file, I have:

```
$colnames[0] = 'ID';
$colnames[1] = 'Name';
$colnames[2] = 'Total';

$colmodel[0] = array("name"=>'ID', "index"=>'libelle', "width"=>50);
$colmodel[1] = array("name"=>'Name',"index"=>'Name', "width"=>50);
$colmodel[2] = array("name"=>'Total', "index"=>'Total', "width"=>50);

$arraydata = array("page"=>"1", 
              "records"=>"1", 
              "total"=>"1", 
              "colnames"=> $colnames,     
              "colmodel"=> $colmodel,         
              "rows"=>$row,
              ...
              );

$jsondata=json_encode($arraydata);  

return $jsondata;
```

(I don't like use json format directly because it's less clear for me and it's difficut to put php variables into json format.)

Secondely, I need to set the cell format dynamically like font color or background color etc..., for example, I want to use "cellattr" in colModel:

```
$colmodel[2] = array("name"=>'Total', "index"=>'Total', "width"=>50, 
"cellattr"=>"function( rowId, val, rowObject, cm, rdata){ if (val>100) return 'style=\"color: orange\"';}");
```

But, I have not the effet "cellattr" in my grid.

Under the Firebug, I have:

```
"colmodel":[{"name":"libelle","cellattr":"function( rowId, val, rowObject, cm, rdata){ return 'style=\"background-color: orange\"';}"
```

I think maybe we can not send a function js in json, I don't know... anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the fixed in Github but I'm not test this fixed.

Change the code in `grid.base.j`s

`acp = celp.split("style");`

to

`acp = celp.split(/[^-]style/);`